# How do I access the value of a textarea with javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea

In one javascript function I am creating a textarea based on some JSON data I am grabbing from another site. I create the textarea here:

```
if(type == 'fill-in'){
    var textField = $('<center><div id="response-text"><textarea id="test" name="test" rows="10" cols="80">Answer here</textarea></div></center>').appendTo(panel.root);                        
}
```

In another function, I need to grab the value of this textfield and send it off to another site. I have tried this in various ways using

```
document.getElementById("test").value
```

But that gives me an error, and if I use

```
document.getElementByName("test").value
```

It tells me that the value is undefined. Do text areas not automatically set their values to whatever you type into them? Is there a better way to grab what is being typed into the textarea?

EDIT:

getElementById is working now... not sure what I was doing before but I must have tried it 3-4 times. I apologize for the pointless question.

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, why dont you use $("#test").val()

Comment: Please show your HTML or better yet, create a jsfiddle.

Comment: What gives `alert(typeof document.getElementById("test"));`?

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated. It hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best **guess** as to what's actually going on in your code and why you may be getting screwed over by [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

I imagine you're trying to dynamically add your text area and then grab a reference right after by using `var test = document.getElementById("test");`. Because of [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), declared variables are **hoisted to the top of the current scope**. This would result in the declaration happening **before** the text area gets added.

As it is unclear where the problem lies with the OP, I did notice that you're using `getElementsByName` incorrectly.

`getElementByName` should be [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName). A subtle but significant difference. Since names do not need to be unique, the function gathers a node list of all DOM elements with a given `name` attribute.

`getElementById` on the other hand returns a reference to the element itself.

[**getElementsByName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName):

> Returns a list of elements with a given name in the HTML document.

[**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById):

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

Comment: This doesn't explain why he's also getting an error when he uses `getElementById`.

Comment: Yeah, I was in the process of updating and thinking at the time - but since I had noticed the issue with `getElementsByName` first, I wanted to go ahead and point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getElementById` works just fine. You must have something wrong with your HTML markup - perhaps another element with the `id` of `test`.

[**Working fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxSJ2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that Teaxarea element is loaded successfully and present in the DOM. In that case, your javascript is loading & executing even before Textarea element is loaded & ready in the DOM.

Regards,